# Can DeferredResult be used together with @ModelAttribute in Spring MVC 4?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, asynchronous

I've just started working a bit with Spring MVC's `DeferredResult` annotation. In the documentation, it is clearly stated that `DeferredResult` can be used as a return type for `@RequestMapping` handler methods. I'm Currently using this feature to populate multiple model fields in parallel, and only calling `setResult` on the `DeferredResult` when all of the fields are ready. This works, but requires quite of bit of synchronization code.

The documentation doesn't touch on the subject of whether returning a `DeferredResult` from a `@ModelAttribute` method is allowed. This would allow me to remove most of the synchronization boilerplate and let Spring worry about how to fit all of this together.

Is it possible to return a `DeferredResult` from a method annotated with `@ModelAttribute`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting with how `DeferredResult` and `@ModelAttribute` work in practice, I found out that using them together simply doesn't work. `DeferredResult` really represents the result of your HTTP request, and you can't use it for model attributes.

This is the state as of Spring 4.0.0